# After changing magento deploy mode to developer site stop working. Magento 2.2.3

Tags: magento2, installation

Fresh installed **Magento 2.2.3** with sample data everything worked fine. until I changed the **deploy: mode** to the **developer** mode. Now it is showing a blank page, there is no error only blank screen.

- Refreshed the cache
- Deleted all cache folders
- Generated folder and cleared **pub/static** folder too `(leaving .htaccess)` file.
- Recompiled the code
- Run **setup upgrade**

commands but without any solution.

please help.

Comment: A blank page usually means php encountered a fatal error. This error should leave additional details in your server's error.log. Adding this error message here would help in getting you an answer which applies to your circumstances.

Comment: Have you got solution?

Answer (score 1):

Please check is your error display is enable, go to `app > bootstrap.php` and find `#ini_set('display_errors', 1);` To `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and check your error.

And you can also your error in `var/log` folder.

I hope it helps to you.

Answer (score 0):

try to run below command once

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:di:compile && php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

let me know if it still blank page

Answer (score 0):

Try below commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:clean
chmod 777 -R generated/
chmod 777 -R var/
```

Refersh your page

Answer (score 0):

Give permission on below dir

> chmod -R 777 generated/ pub/static/ var/

If still not working then please add below code at the top position in index.php on the root and find cause of the error.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```